# error when create new portlet pulgin in liferay

Tags: java, liferay-7

error:-**returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://cdn.lfrs.sl/repository.liferay.com/nexus/content/repositories/liferay-public-snapshots/com/liferay/org.apache.ivy/2.4.0.LIFERAY-PATCHED-1-SNAPSHOT/org.apache.ivy-2.4.0.LIFERAY-PATCHED-1-SNAPSHOT.jar**

BUILD FAILED
E:\Liferay\com.liferay.portal.plugins.sdk-1.0.11-withdependencies\portlets\build.xml:5: The following error occurred while executing this line:
E:\Liferay\com.liferay.portal.plugins.sdk-1.0.11-withdependencies\build-common-plugins.xml:5: The following error occurred while executing this line:
E:\Liferay\com.liferay.portal.plugins.sdk-1.0.11-withdependencies\build-common.xml:57: The following error occurred while executing this line:
E:\Liferay\com.liferay.portal.plugins.sdk-1.0.11-withdependencies\build-common-ivy.xml:41: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://cdn.lfrs.sl/repository.liferay.com/nexus/content/repositories/liferay-public-snapshots/com/liferay/org.apache.ivy/2.4.0.LIFERAY-PATCHED-1-SNAPSHOT/org.apache.ivy-2.4.0.LIFERAY-PATCHED-1-SNAPSHOT.jar

Total time: 2 seconds

**I have created new portlet and connect to plugins when problem is occur as mention above.**

**I have download jar and set in .ivy folder but again same problem occur.
please give me different sloution.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. In your liferay-plugins-sdk, find the file named build.prpoerties.
2. Localte **ivy.jar.url** in build.properties.
3. Replace:

   ```
   ivy.jar.url=https://cdn.lfrs.sl/repository.liferay.com/nexus/content/repositories/liferay-public-snapshots/com/liferay/org.apache.ivy/${ivy.version}/org.apache.ivy-${ivy.version}.jar
   ```

with:

```
    ivy.jar.url=https://repository.liferay.com/nexus/content/repositories/liferay-public-snapshots/com/liferay/org.apache.ivy/${ivy.version}/org.apache.ivy-${ivy.version}.jar
```